# Как отобразить в DataGrid поля объекта?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, entity-framework

Есть `DataGrid`  в которой нужно выводить информацию из базы данных. К примеру у меня есть класс:

```
public partial class Orders
    {
        public Orders()
        {
            this.CustomersOrders = new HashSet<CustomersOrders>();
            this.OrdersProducts = new HashSet<OrdersProducts>();
        }

        public int order_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> order_prodCount { get; set; }
        public string order_dateils { get; set; }
        public string order_status { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime order_date { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CustomersOrders> CustomersOrders { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrdersProducts> OrdersProducts { get; 

set; }
}
```

класс `Orders` связан с классом  `Customers` и `Products` через связь многие ко многим

```
  public partial class CustomersOrders
    {
        public int customersOrders_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> order_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> cust_id { get; set; }

        public virtual Customers Customers { get; set; }
        public virtual Orders Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

И

```
  public partial class OrdersProducts
    {
        public int ordersProducts_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> order_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> prod_id { get; set; }

        public virtual Orders Orders { get; set; }
        public virtual Products Products { get; set; }
    }
```

как мне вывести `Products` и `Customers`, конкретно `prod_name` из `Products` и `custom_name`  `custom_Surname` из `Customers`  в мой `DataGrid` в месте с   `order_dateils, order_status, order_date`
И как связать это всё с `XAML`?

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product" Binding="{Binding .....???}"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer" Binding="{Binding .....???}"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding order_status}"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dateils" Binding="{Binding order_dateils}"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Date" Binding="{Binding order_date}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: `Orders` содержит две коллекции: `CustomersOrders` и `OrdersProducts`. Вы хотите отобразить два грида под эти две коллекции?

Comment: Я хочу, чтоб информация из Orders (order_dateils, order_status, order_date)  выводилась в месте с Products и Customers, конкретно prod_name из Products и custom_name custom_Surname из Customers в мой DataGrid.

Comment: Т.е. ячейка `Header="Product"` должна принять в себя коллекцию `ICollection<OrdersProducts> OrdersProducts`, найти в этой коллекции итем с `order_id` таким же как в `Orders.order_id` и вывести `prod_name` этого итема? Это можно сделать через конвертер, типа `Binding="{Binding OrdersProducts, Converter={StaticResource OrdersProductsConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding order_id}}"`.

Comment: Вы правильно поняли. Подскажите как мне описать Resource OrdersProductsConverter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идею изложил в комментарии, здесь уже конкретный пример:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(ICollection<OrdersProducts>), typeof(string))]
public class OrdersProductsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var collection = value as ICollection<OrdersProducts>;
        var id = (int)parameter;

        return collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.order_id == id)?.Products.prod_name;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

И объявляем в ресурсах:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:OrdersProductsConverter x:Key="OrdersProductsConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Нюансы типа `Nullable<int>` и нэймспейсов - это уж за вами :)  Но идея рабочая.

**Обновление**
Исходный вариант писал с ходу, запамятовал что конвертер_параметр - не депенденси. Посему, самый грамотный вариант - сделать мультибиндинг как в [этом примере](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15309844/5177728). А самый быстрый вариант - просто принять в конвертер сам итем, чьи проперти выводятся в ячейках.

То есть биндимся так:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Product" Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource OrdersProductsConverter}, Path=.}"/>
```

А рабочий материал в конвертере получаем так:

```
var item = (Orders)value;
var collection = item.OrdersProducts;
var id = item.order_id;
```

Comment: Сделал всё, как Вы описали,  но как бороться с "Error 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'ConverterParameter' property of type 'Binding'. 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject." ?

Comment: Я обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо заработало, а как быть если нужно вернуть более одного элемента. К примеру имя и фамилию покупателя? Я так понимаю класс конвертер возвращает массив objectов состоящий из 2х элементов. Подскажите, как распарсить это в xaml?

Comment: Как вы хотите отобразить более одного объекта в одной ячейке? Конвертер возвращает объект, в вашем случае это строка `prod_name`. Она и помещается в ячейку. Если вы хотите сформировать более сложную строку из нескольких компонентов, это следует делать здесь же, в конвертере, и возвращать результирующую строку. Также, вы можете сформировать в конвертере графический объект (например `StackPanel` с кастомным содержимым), и возвращать его.